# Scrape website dynamic content - server side

Tags: php, ajax

I have spent several hours of researching to find a solution, but I couldn't solve the issue. I have an ASO service website (like sensortower) where I need to check android application rankings by keyword. So I need a script which navigates to the Play Store and find our customers app's position in the search listing results.

I could scrape perfectly in the first ~20 results (file_get_contents), but usually there is 250 results when you scroll down to the bottom (dynamically loaded contents). I've tried using phantomjs, curl but possibly I need something else to solve this problem.

Here is the code which works for the ~20 results:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://play.google.com/store/search?q=war+games&c=apps');
preg_match_all("/data-docid=\"([^\"]*)\"/i", $html, $data);

$list = array_keys(array_flip($data[1]));
$packageNameToSearchFor = 'com.lighting.commander';

if (in_array($packageNameToSearchFor, $list)) {
    $order = array_search($packageNameToSearchFor, $list)+1;

    echo 'Position: '.$order;
} else {
    echo 'Not found!';
}
```

I appreciate every help or tips.

Comment: If the page loads the content via AJAX, can you capture that AJAX request in your browser and replicate that request in code?  Then just scrape that data instead of the page.

Comment: @David Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the AJAX token is protected.

Comment: @David Yep indeed there is something strange with their ajax requests. Obviously to make this kind of "data retrieving" a little harder.
Maybe this implementation of a Play Store scraper could help https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/blob/dev/lib/search.js

Comment: @David I'll have a look later. Your answer is the best so far. Thanks